# Context free grammar for {a*b*c*} - {a^n b^n c^n | n >=0}

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm having trouble with this problem.  I believe its telling me that no string can be generated that has even # of a's b's and c's.  This is due to the subtraction of the second set.

A good string from a newly formed CFG should be something like aaabbc or abbbcc and so on.

So I tried breaking the problem into three parts...

1. Single states

   ```
   a.) S(1) -> aS(1) | a | ^
   b.) S(2) -> bS(2) | b | ^
   c.) S(3) -> cS(2) | b | ^
   ```
2. Two States

   ```
   a.) S(4) -> aS(4)b | S(1) | S(2)
   b.) S(5) -> bS(5)c | S(2)
   c.) S(6) -> aS(6)c | S(3) | S(1)
   ```
3. States w/AB states

   ```
   a.) S(7) -> S(1) | S(4)S(6)
   b.) S(8) -> S(2) | S(5)S(6)
   c.) S(9) -> S(3) | S(6)S(3)
   ```

   with an orginal start state of   ...

   ```
   S ->  S(7) | S(8) | S(9)
   ```

However I'm having problems building strings like aaaabbbcc ...

Am I forming CFGs incorrectly?  I felt like I was on the right track but now I'm quite lost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Strictly computer science-related questions should be asked at http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I searched before and there all quite a few grammar questions on here that weren't closed.  It relates directly to programming a DFA btw.  My goal is to finish this grammar then make a DFA that represents it and then code it in java.  Sounds like programming to me.

Comment: The presence of off-topic questions doesn't mean that future off-topic questions are acceptable. This is just one down-vote, if no one agrees then the question will remain open.

Comment: {a^n b^n c^n | n >=0} is per definition not a CFG. I can't remember what the rules say but I do not know if a CFG - nonCFG can equal a CFG. Have you tried ogdens' lemma to determine if it is indeed a CFG

Comment: yes, that part is not a CFG by definition.  However its being subtracted from (abc)* which is creates a string that can never have the form of a=b=c such as aabbcc.  The newly formed language becomes a CFG that is {(abc)* | where a=b=c does not exist in the language}

Comment: (abc)* is not the new language. Since it will then look like abcabcabcabc.... your question says a*b*c* which is different from (abc)*

Comment: a* b* c* (correction on "your question says abc*")

Comment: @Murdock: Neither the set of CFG nor the set of non-CFGs are closed under inversion or disjunction. And this language is context-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So I split the problem into 2 sub problems**

The number of a's is different from the number of b's. Therefore the a's and c's or b's and c's can be the same.

The number of b's is different from the number of c's. Therefore the a's and b's or a's and c's can be the same.

**Edit**: More formally as stated by Rici {a<sup>*n*</sup>b<sup>*m*</sup>c<sup>*</sup> | *n* ≠ *m* } ∪ {a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>*n*</sup>c<sup>*m*</sup> | *n* ≠ *m* }

```
//a and b is different
S-->XR
//b and c is different
S-->DY

//Genarates a string where a is more than b
X--> aXb | A
A --> aA  | a

//Genarates a string where b is more than a
X--> bXa | B
B --> bB  | b

//Genarates a string where b is more than c
Y--> bYc | B
B --> bB  | b

//Genarates a string where c is more than b
Y--> cYb | C
C --> cC  | c

R-->Rc|c|^
D-->Da|a|^
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler expression for this language is:

{a<sup>*n*</sup>b<sup>*m*</sup>c<sup>*</sup> | *n* ≠ *m* } ∪ {a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>*n*</sup>c<sup>*m*</sup> | *n* ≠ *m* }

(Using the Kleene star above is probably an abuse of notation. Originally, I wrote it with a third integer variable. But I think the star is clearer.)

Now, {a<sup>*n*</sup>b<sup>*m*</sup> | *n* ≠ *m* } is simply a<sup>*n*</sup>(a<sup>+</sup>|b<sup>+</sup>)b<sup>*n*</sup>

So the full expression could be written as a<sup>*n*</sup>(a<sup>+</sup>|b<sup>+</sup>)b<sup>*n*</sup>c<sup>*</sup> | a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>*n*</sup>(b<sup>+</sup>|c<sup>+</sup>)c<sup>*n*</sup>

Putting all that together into a CFG is a little tedious so <s>I left it for the reader</s>waited seven years before writing it. It's almost  totally mechanical.

```
S -> A R | L C
# "Left" a^mb^n m ≠ n
L -> a A | b B | a L b
# "Right" b^mc^n m ≠ n
R -> b B | c C | b R c
# zero or more a's (b's, c's)
A -> a A | ε
B -> b B | ε
C -> c C | ε
```

Making a DFA (or more properly Deterministic Pushdown Automaton) out of that might be trickier, since the CFG is ambiguous. In fact, *every* CFG for that language is ambiguous. But there's no problem making an NDPA.

Comment: Why is not a 3rd set there in the first expression you wrote? E.g. $${a^n b^* c^m | n \neq m}$$

Comment: @Zargo: everything in that set is already in one of the two I mention..So it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above by Murdock is very close but fails some cases. For example it can generate a, b and aabcc as it should, but cannot generate c, abbcc or bc even though it should be able to. (JFlap is a great software I use for quickly testing different strings on grammers I am constructing, it is also helpful for a lot of other concepts in formal languages and computational theory.)
Using Murdock's CFG it is also possible for the letters to appear in different order, but the question statement forces all a's to come first, followed by all b's and finally all c's.

Danish Ahmed seems to have misunderstood the question and tried to construct a CFG for the language where a's, b's and c's are all in equal amounts. Off the top of their head, my lecturer has said it is impossible to construct a CFG for this. Danish's CFG is incorrect for a = b = c because it can generate a 'b' by itself through S -> X; X -> BX; X -> null (also assuming the capital B was meant to be a terminal b.)

Here is my answer, which adds to and adjusts some components of Murdock's CFG so that it is valid for the question.

```
S=XR|DY|WR|DZ
X=aXb|A
A=aA|a
W=aWb|B
B=bB|b
Y=bYc|B
Z=bZc|C
C=cC|c
R=Rc|c|epsilon
D=Da|a|epsilon
```

Answer (score -1):

Context Free Grammer for the language of a^n b^n c^n can be constructed using given production.

```
S -> aSc | X
X -> BX
X -> null
```

Using the above production you can generate a^n b^n c^n. Suppose we're generating a^2 b^2 c^2. we will start from S.

```
= aSc
= aaScc ; aSc
= aaXcc ; S -> X
= aabXcc ; X -> bX
= aabbXcc ; X -> bX
= aabb(null)cc ; X -> null
= aabbcc
```

Comment: This grammar is incorrect.  It can generate the words ac and abbbbc, which are not in the language {a^n b^n c^n}.  Also, the grammar has an obvious typo; presumably BX should be bX.  Finally, the language {a^n b^n c^n} is not what the question was asking about anyway, so it's not even answering the question.